# Xamarin Listview Item Source Binding not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have a small project that has two pages showing a list view. But one of my pages is not working in spite of beeing the same code with just small changes (names of props).
The binding context it´s taking the information i need (the Patients list) but the page returns empty. In my other page with the same code the Viewlist works properly.
Maybe i'm missing something or could be a typo error i really don't know what's happening.
Please help me and if u have suggestions to improve my code please tell me i'm a begginer in xamarin forms.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="appointmentListView"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}">
    <ListView.Header>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="#03A9F4">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="15,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:DataType="model:Appointment">
                    <Label  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                Text="{Binding Patient}" 
                FontSize="24"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AppointmentListViewDetail : ContentPage
{
    public AppointmentListViewDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new AppointmentListViewModel();

        appointmentListView.ItemSelected += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem as Appointment != null)
            {
                Action goToPage = async () =>
                {
                    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new AppointmentDetailsPopup(e.SelectedItem as Appointment));
                    appointmentListView.SelectedItem = null;
                };
                goToPage.Invoke();
            }
        };
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AppointmentListViewModel>(this, "Reload", (p) =>
        {
            BindingContext = p;
        });

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AppointmentFilterViewModel>(this, "Filter", (p) =>
        {
            string? nameFilter = p.NameFilter.Text;
            DateTime? startDateFilter = DateTime.ParseExact(p.StartDateFilter.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime? finalDateFilter = DateTime.ParseExact(p.FinalDateFilter.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Status? statusFilter = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), p.StatusFilter.Text);

            BindingContext = new AppointmentListViewModel(nameFilter, startDateFilter, finalDateFilter, statusFilter);
        });

    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AppointmentListViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<Appointment> _appointments;
    public ObservableCollection<Appointment> Appointments
    {
        get { return _appointments; }
        set
        {
            _appointments = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Appointments));
        }
    }

    public ICommand Filter { get; set; }

    public AppointmentListViewModel()
    {
        var getAppointmentsList = new Action(async () =>
        {
            Appointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>(await Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppointmentService>().ToListAsync());
        });

        getAppointmentsList.Invoke();

    }
    public AppointmentListViewModel(string? patient, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? finalDate, Status? status)
    {
        var getPatientList = new Action(async () =>
        {
            Appointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>(await Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppointmentService>().FilterSearchAsync(patient, startDate, finalDate, status));
        });

        getPatientList.Invoke();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


}
```

Model:

```
    public class Appointment
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public float Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Status PaymentStatus { get; set; }

    public string Patient { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: try hardcoding `Appointments` to a list of test data and comment out all of the other code that loads that data.  If that works then you know the problem is in how your VM is loading the data

Comment: Did you try to debug this? Does your Appointments collection contain anything once the setter is called, if it ever gets called?

Comment: @Jason thanks for suggesting that the problem was how my VM was loading the data.  Btw i debbuged but i was not finding the error so thanks again!

Comment: If possible, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: I solved this problem using Task.Run().Wait() it turns out that the page was loading before  getting the data. Thanks everybody!

Comment: You can post your solution id you have figured it out as it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using Task.Run().Wait(). I recommend using this if u are trying to get data from the database on your viewmodel.

ViewModel:

```
 public AppointmentListViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Appointments = new ObservableCollection<Appointment>(await Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppointmentService>().ToListAsync());
        }).Wait();
    }
```

Service that contains all operations related to the database:

```
    public AppointmentService()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "patient.db3");
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<Appointment>().Wait();
    }


    public Task<List<Appointment>> ToListAsync()
    {
        return _database.Table<Appointment>().ToListAsync();
    }
```